# Type long Vs Type long int

Tags: c

What would following typedef mean, and why would it be required

```
typedef unsigned long int ULONG;
```

how different is it from

```
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
```

For gcc sizeof int = 4, sizeof long = 8, and sizeof ULONG = 8.

Comment: "For gcc sizeof int = 4, sizeof long = 8" -- not on 32 bit systems. Nor in Mingw64, for that matter. The sizes of the types are more-or-less determined by the ABI that GCC is going to use to call OS libraries. "More or less" because I'm pretty sure you could do a build of GCC where the types don't match the OS, you'd just have some extra headaches calling code that wasn't compiled by your build of GCC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same. Because `long` is a modifier for an `int` by default, `int` can be omitted. The same goes for `short` and `short int`, `unsigned` and `unsigned int`, etc.

The essential thing to understand here is that `long`, `short` and `unsigned` are *type modifiers*, not types themselves, unlike `int`, `char`, `double`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference at all. `long` is synonymous with `long int` (just as `short` is with `short int`).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `unsigned long` is not defined in C++ Standard ISO/IEC 14882 so, if it works for you, it is only because your compiler is interpreting `unsigned long int` as `unsigned long`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Table 10 in section §7.1.6.2 'Simple type specifiers' of ISO/IEC 14882:2011 defines `unsigned long` as a valid type specifier, equivalent to `unsigned long int`.  (You're right that section §3.9.1 'Fundamental types' does not list `unsigned long`.)

Answer (score -1):

The size of long is not related to gcc but os